# Which existing model could be used for wind speed and direction prediction?

Tags: datasets, regression, model-request

I am trying to predict the wind speed and wind direction in a graph network for a geographical area. The dataset includes the start and end nodes, the distance between them, and wind speed and direction. I want to predict the wind speed and direction for a certain number of line segments (edges) in a graph network.

Which existing prediction model could be used for this problem? For example, my dependent and independent variables are wind speed and wind direction. How these can be used to predict their future values?

Note: The network here represents a graphical network constructed using NetworkX Python library. Nodes represent the cities and edges represent the distance between the cities. Furthermore, I am currently having a dummy dataset for wind speed and wind direction for each edge. Using this data, I want to predict the wind speed and wind direction for a certain number of edges that are between a given source and destination.

Comment: When you say "graph network", do you mean a "graph neural network" or "graphical network" (like a Bayesian network)? I suppose you're talking about the first. If yes, you can edit your post to use the tag [tag:graph-neural-networks].

Comment: @nbro I meant a graph-based network built using the NetworkX python library.

Comment: So, you don't mean a "neural network", but just a graph, correct?

Comment: Can you please explain what the nodes and edges in your graph represent then? You say "I want to predict the wind speed and direction for a certain number of line segments (edges) in a graph network", but what does it even mean? This depends on what a edge represents.

Comment: Yes, it is just a graph. Nodes represent the cities and edges represent the distance between the cities. Furthermore, I am currently having a dummy dataset for wind speed and wind direction for each edge. Using this data, I want to predict the wind speed and wind direction for a certain number of edges that are between a given source and destination.

Comment: I recommend that you edit your post to include this info directly there because comments are meant to be temporary and can later be deleted.